# Filter in Sitecore Children in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I have this tree structure:

```
Page1
  PageA
    PageX
    PageY
  PageB
Page2
```

I want Page1 and Page2 as well as all child pages. I have created two classes. In one class using sitecore query

```cs
[SitecoreQuery("../*[@@templateid={GUID}]", IsRelative = true)]
public virtual IEnumerable<ItemModel> Links { get; set; }
```

In other ItemModel class getting child pages

```cs
public class ItemModel
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren]
    public IEnumerable<SideMenuModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This is working fine but now I want to get only those child pages who have some specific template. Please provide me some solution.

Comment: Can I ask for your contact (eg skype, email etc). I want to learn sitecore. I'm still a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have most of the code correct but you need to also apply restrictions to the `Children` property on the `ItemModel` class.

You can use a `SitecoreQuery` on the like you have on the parent model:

```cs
public class ItemModel
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid={SideMenuModel-GUID}]", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SideMenuModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use the `EnforceTemplate` attribute on your `SideMenuModel` class:

```cs
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "GUID", EnforceTemplate = SitecoreEnforceTemplate.Template)]
public class SideMenuModel
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ItemModel
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<SideMenuModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
}
```

Since you have set `EnforceTemplate` then using the `[SitecoreChildren]` attribute means that only items matching the template id will be returned, otherwise they will be skipped.

If you need children of children mapped then you should add `[SitecoreChildren]` property on your `SideMenuModel` class as well (or refactor your code so the class references itself) or you could use a "get all descendants query (`.//*[@@templateid={SideMenuModel-GUID}]`) although I would recommend that you ur he Content Search API at this point instead.

You can read more in the blog post about [Getting child items with Glass](http://www.glass.lu/Blog/GettingChildItems).